# Meu teclado e mouse não interage com Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

Eu estou tentando usar bibliotecas como selenium, pyautogui e keyboard e elas não conseguem interagir com o meu teclado e mouse.

Eu uso as funções:

`pyautogui.click(x,y)` e `pyautogui.hotkeys("ctrl","t")`

Nenhuma das duas dá erro, mas também não acontece nada.
Tentei no *Jupyter Notebook*, *Google Collab*, *PyCharm* e *Visual Code Studio* e não funciona nas três. Outras funções funcionam.

No selenium, aparece um erro que tentei pesquisar e corrigir de diversas formas, como utilizando o `Options()` e o `Service()`, mas também não funcionam. Coloquei o path corretamente e baixar os arquivos necessários (*webdriver* e afins).

Como resolver meu problema?

Comment: Poderia por obséquio adicionar um [mcve] mostrando de maneira enxuta o seu código com problemas para que possamos avaliar. Pois da maneira que apresenta o problema sem mostrar o código é inviável pontuar uma solução, cabendo apenas negativar e votar para fechar a pergunta. Veja [ask], [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387), [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101), [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/137387) e faça o nosso [tour]

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia, se seu sistema operacional for linux, verifique se não precisa dar permissão as portas do mouse e teclado.

```
sudo chmod 777 [endereço da porta]
```

ou

```
sudo chmod a+rw [endereço da porta]
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).